# What is the best method for holding granola together in clusters?

Tags: baking

My son loves a certain brand of granola, which used to be sold with a lot of large clusters. Now it is more of a loose cereal--he has difficulty with fine motor use of a spoon.

Can I mix the loose cereal style with egg whites and bake in the oven to create my own clusters? Are there any other techniques or suggestions I should try?

Answer (score 2):

Egg whites is widely suggested as a way to do this.  I also see honey being recommended.  In either case, don't mix the granola as it cooks, perhaps turn the larger chunks gently, 1/2 way (or more) through the cooking time.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen [recipes](https://www.bonappetit.com/story/how-to-make-the-most-cluster-y-granola) that call for using bran cereal flakes and wheat germ with egg whites to create clusters that form and stay together. Also supposed to let it cool completely before breaking apart.